# Subcaption ragged right

Tags: subcaption

How do I make the subcaptions ragged right for just one figure environment and not the whole document? I need this for an image grid containing 20 small figures and I am using the `\subcaptionbox`.

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{25.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{26.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{27.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{28.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{Al}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{29.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{30.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{31.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{32.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{33.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{Re}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{34.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{35.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{36.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{37.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{38.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{Ta}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{39.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox*{0,1 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{40.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{25 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{41.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{750 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{42.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{1618,55 s}{\includegraphics[width=1.2in,height=1.2in]{43.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox*{W [wt\%]}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=1.2in]{44.png}}\\
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
```

Inside the `figure` environment. If this is also to apply for short captions spanning just one line `singlelinecheck=off` has to be added,

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I added my code to the question. Please check.

Comment: @abdu please see my updated answer.